# CSV parsing through PHP

Tags: php

I am working in CSV parsing in php where we have one column in CSV i.e 'Amount' which have value like this ($45.34).
So, when we see these value in excel sheet it will show same value but if we see these value in formula bar in excel it will show me -45.34 (i.e negative value).So i have not parse these value as negative value as we need??

Comment: This statement is confusing ... is the value supposed to be negative and you are parsing it as positive, or vice versa? Also, please include the PHP you are using to parse said CSV.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't really understand what you're asking here. I realise there is probably a language barrier here - perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: Please provide the actual csv line that contains the value in question.

Comment: I think you are parsing CSV file. just print the cell value on parsing in PHP

Comment: PlantTheIdea - I am parsing it as positive value because the csv cell value is sowing me positive i.e ($45.34) but in formula bar its vaue is negative i.e -45.34 which we exactly need.